# Camera blockage detection that is mounted on a car

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm developing an algorithm that detects a camera blockage using python OpenCV.

Actually, as I'm not good at computer vision yet i'm not sure if the algorithm I came up with is appropriate.

Can anybody take a look at the code I made?

```
def detectCameraBlockage_absdiff():

cnt = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# print('width: ', cap.get(3))
# print('height: ', cap.get(4))
IMAGE_WIDTH = cap.get(3)
IMAGE_HEIGHT = cap.get(4)
background = np.zeros((480, 640))

while True:
    if cnt == 0:
        cnt += 1
        pass

    else:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('if you want to quit press the key [q]', frame)
            # cv2.imshow('if you want to quit press the key [q]', frame[:, :, 0])

            mean_frame = frame.mean(axis=2)
            # cv2.imshow('mean_frame', mean_frame)

            diff = cv2.absdiff(background, mean_frame)
            # print(type(diff))
            cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
            _, diff = cv2.threshold(diff, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            # print(type(_), type(diff), sep='\n') #float, ndarray



            if cnt%10 == 0:
                background = mean_frame

            cnt += 1
            print('cnt: ', cnt)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break            

        else:
            print('camera failed.')
            break
```

This code doesn't work for me.

I cannot think out how should i deal with that pixel values to get the difference between the image that has no blockage and that has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to measure the similarity between a reference image and the current image. The reference image would be the image without the blockage.

If your camera is static, a simple way to implement it is to use SSIM (https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d5/dc4/tutorial_video_input_psnr_ssim.html).

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I experimented with SSIM algorithm. But my cam is mounted on a car, I dont think SSIM is fit my problem.. The value that ssim returns changed a lot with a little camera movement. Anyway thank you for replying!